# Adding to the left column based on whether there is a symbol is the right column (pandas df)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `df` as the following.

| Number | Word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 1 1 | a b c |
| 2 2 | hi it's |
| 3 3 3 3 | hello world hi everyone |
| 4 | can't |

I want to detect whether there is an apostrophe in the word on the right, and add the same number that is on the left in the corresponding row 2 times.

i.e. The output should be like the following.

| Number | Word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 1 1 | a b c |
| 2 2 2 2 | hi it's |

Because there is an apostrophe in "it's" on the right in the second row, I want to add the same number twice on the left to the same cell.

I tried the following.

```
if df1['Word'].str.contains("'").any():
  l.append(df1.iloc[0]['I'])
```

But I'm unsure about what to do after.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a conditional statement with `np.where` to update the Number column accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': ['1 1 1', '2 2', '3 3 3 3', '4'],
 'Word': ['a b c', "hi it's", 'hello world hi everyone', "can't"]})

df['Number'] = np.where(df['Word'].str.contains("'"),
                        df['Number'] + ' ' + df.Number.str.split().str[0] + ' ' + df.Number.str.split().str[0],
                        df['Number'])
```

Output

```
    Number                     Word
0    1 1 1                    a b c
1  2 2 2 2                  hi it's
2  3 3 3 3  hello world hi everyone
3    4 4 4                    can't
```

Answer (score 2):

**don't think difficult**, your solution is simple:

```
df1.apply(check_apostrophe, axis=1)
```

with [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method and set `axis=1` you can apply a function to each row, my function is `check_apostrophe`:

```
def check_apostrophe(x):
    if "'" in str(x["Word"]):
        x["Number"] = repeat(x["Number"])
    return x

def repeat(string):
    string += " "+string[-1] #if your string is striped
    return string
```

**test:** https://onecompiler.com/python/3xfve7kur

result:

| Number | Word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 1 1 | a b c |
| 2 2 2 | hi it's |
| 3 3 3 3 | hello world hi everyone |
| 4 4 | can't |